# wordpress : what value the $m variable holds

Tags: php, wordpress

I found a variable $m on get_calendar() function, (in Calendar widget) its not month, we have $monthnum. I tried to echo the value. it always shows 0 (on the calendar widget)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$m` is a global query variable that is set through url like `/?m=201311`

Comment: what m=201311 stands for what ? what is the meaning of the value?

Comment: its part of url , which is made global with global $m, and it can contain date like yearmonth, such as 201310 i.e year:: 2013 and month:: 10